# Django - Selecting from multiple tables/models

Tags: django

I have a model set up that is

```
class BasePage(Page):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PageTypeA(BasePage):
    ...

class PageTypeB(BasePage):
    ...

class PageTypeC(BasePage):
    ...

etc..
```

How do I create a query to list all of the pages that inherit from BasePage?

Comment: Could you include the code for your Page model? I'm confused about what's going on here, as your BasePage looks to be an abstract base class, but it does not inherit from models.Model.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understand you properly you need a parent model that have some generic information and other child models need some extra additional information. You can try third-party `django-polymorphic` [link](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for that. One of important feature that it support `Django-Rest-Framework` serializer too.